# Unique entries across multiple list

Tags: python, loops, recursion, reduce

I am building a fixture manager for a sport event.

To simplify the program:

There are four teams in a group. They play both home and away matches. So, in total 6 matches, happens across 6 weeks. So, total combination of "possible matches" at the start would look like this. (I have similar data structure in my code)

```
from itertools import combinations

teams = ["Swin", "Lon", "Key", "Stran"]
dates = ["2023/05/17", "2023/05/22", "2023/05/29", "2023/05/17", "2023/05/22", "2023/05/29"]

possibilities = []
for the_date in dates:
  for match in combinations(teams, 2):
    possibilities.append({"Home": match[0], "Away": match[1], "Date": the_date})
    possibilities.append({"Home": match[1], "Away": match[0], "Date": the_date})

for i in  possibilities:
   print (i)
```

From the "possibilities", I want to get only valid set of possibilities, which is basically satisfying:

- No two team combination is playing same match type (Home, Away) twice
- Neither of the "Home" and "Away" teams are playing on the same "Date" twice

What is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: There a thousands calendar variations, do you want them all?, justo the first date you can come up with (12)(2) = 24 variations, for the second date (10)(2) = 20 variations

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you all 46080 possible calendars

```
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import permutations

teams = ["Swin", "Lon", "Key", "Stran"]
dates = ["2023/05/17", "2023/05/22", "2023/05/29", "2023/05/17", "2023/05/22", "2023/05/29"]

possibilities = {}
mbt={}
matches=[]
for match in combinations(teams, 2):
    t1,t2 = match
    matches.append((t1,t2,0))
    matches.append((t1,t2,1))

mpd=[]
for m in [ x for x in matches if x[0]==teams[0] or x[1] ==teams[0]]:
    already=[m[0],m[1]]
    for m2 in [mx for mx in matches if mx[0] not in already and mx[1] not in already]:
        mpd.append((m,m2))
     
    
calendars=[]
c=0
for d1 in matches[0:2]:
    for d2 in matches[2:4]:
        for d3 in matches[4:6]:
            for d4 in matches[6:8]:
                for d5 in matches[8:10]:
                    for d6 in matches[10:12]:
                        for pm in permutations([d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6],6):
                            cal=[]
                            for i in range(6):
                                if pm[0]==0:
                                    t1=pm[i][0];t2=pm[i][1]
                                else:
                                    t1=pm[i][1];t2=pm[i][0]
                                cal.append({"Home": t1, "Away": t2, "Date": dates[i]})
                                
                            calendars.append(cal)
#print any of the 46080 possible calendars                            
for line in calendars[0]:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give me some explanation of the solution

Comment: Yes i can comment on it, but could you please accept the answer